# How can i do sentiment analysis on only one sentence?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I am currently trying to do a sentiment analysis program on a dataset provided by tensorflow. This code works, however, i do not know how to predict if only one sentence is positive or negative ( its probability ). The testing is done on the dataset firstly and it works fine. I know there is something that i am missing, but i can't figure out what it is.

This is the code ( i thought it might help):

```
train_validation_split = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit([6, 4])

(train_data, validation_data), test_data = tfds.load(
    name="imdb_reviews",
    split=(train_validation_split, tfds.Split.TEST),
    as_supervised=True)

train_examples_batch, train_labels_batch = next(iter(train_data.batch(10)))

embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1" 
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[],
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.summary() #vom printa un rezumat al modelului final
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_data.shuffle(10000).batch(512),
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_data=validation_data.batch(512),
                    verbose=1)

results = model.evaluate(test_data.batch(512), verbose=2)

for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, results):
  print("%s: %.3f" % (name, value))
```

And this is what i tried adding to it in order to test the sentiment analysis only on this one sentence:

```
test_sentence = " I don't like this movie. I actually hate it."
result = model.evaluate(test_sentence, verbose=2)
for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, result):
  print("%s: %.3f" % (name, value))
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: So, what is the output after executing this?

Comment: @Strange the first code executes fine and the output is : loss: 0.340
accuracy: 0.853 . However, the second one gives a lot of errors such as IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: pass it in a list and try to execute once again.

Comment: @strange this is the output that i got now : IndexError: list index out of range
1/1 -0s. This proves that the sentence was, however, processed, considering that the above code returned : 49/49 - 2s  before displaying the loss and accuracy

Comment: what does this 49/49 -2s mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: @strange sure, it means that 49 batches were "executed" in 2 seconds, and in this case, 1/1 ( cause i only have one batch) was executed in 0 seconds

Comment: Instead of using neural networks,  you can implement sentiment analysis using naive bayes classifier,  which you can implement it yourself using python, check this video: https://youtu.be/doznOnG81xY